# How to find out the number of digits of an oracle number

Tags: oracle, plsql, precision

I have a table in oracle that looks like this:

```
name              |     type    | nullable  
------------------------------------------
person_name       | varchar(20) | yes  
weight_coeficient | number      | yes
...
```

How can I figure out **how many digits a value of weight_coeficient** has ? For example:

`3.0123456789` has 11 digits ([precision](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832) = 11) and 10 digits after the decimal ([scale](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832) = 10)

Is there any sql command/function that does that, something like `GetPrecision( select.. )` that returns 11 ?

Note also that the definition of the table does not specify scale and precision. So as far as I know the maximum precision is applied for all the numbers. So I'm not interested in finding out the precision (= 48) of the definition, but the precision of a specific value in the table. Is that possible just using oracle commands ?

Thank you in advance, 
JP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about....

```
SELECT LENGTH(TRANSLATE(TO_CHAR(3.0123456789),'1234567890.-','1234567890')) 
FROM dual
```

The translate simply removes the non numeric characters `.-`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But `3.0123456789` was an example. How can I adapt the code you wrote to use `weight_coeficient` instead considering that the table name is `Coeficients`? I would expect something like `SELECT LENGTH(TRANSLATE(Select weight_coeficient from Coeficients where name = 'John Paul'),'1234567890.-','1234567890')) FROM dual` or something. But this doesn't work. Sorry.. I'm not too good at sql sintax

Comment: @John Paul: You'd be much better off with `SELECT LENGTH(TRANSLATE(weight_coeficient),'1234567890.-','1234567890')) from Coeficients where name = 'John Paul';`

Comment: @Allan: good tip, but you have an extra parenthesis.  I think it should be `SELECT LENGTH(TRANSLATE(weight_coeficient,'1234567890.-','1234567890')) from...`

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement is to use:

```
length(to_char(:number)) - coalesce(length(translate(to_char(:number), 'x1234567890', 'x')), 0)
```

When you to_char inserts an 'E' for exponential or a different grouping character or decimal separator, it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to generate a the appropriate casts for your data. I wrote this to help move NUMBER data with unspecified precision & scale in Oracle to Postgres, via Kafka-Connect. Kafka-Connect lets one select data  to copy over to another database via query, but since we did not have our number precision set on the Oracle side, Kafka-Connect was inserting everything into Postgres as a big decimal. I.e, an Oracle 1 would be inserted as 1.000000000<30 decimals>.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   Q1    VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR);
   str   VARCHAR2 (300 CHAR);
BEGIN
   FOR rec
      IN (SELECT  column_name AS column_name
            FROM all_tab_cols
           WHERE     owner = 'YOUR_SCHEMA'
                 AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
                 AND DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER')
   LOOP
      q1 :=
         'SELECT    REPLACE(''cast( ''
             || :1
             || '' as  NUMBER(''
             || TO_CHAR (MAX (LENGTH_OF_DECIMAL) + MAX (length_of_integer))
             || '',''
             || TO_CHAR (MAX (length_of_decimal))
             || ''))'',''NUMBER(0,0)'',''NUMBER'') as result
        FROM (SELECT charnum,
                     CASE
                        WHEN INSTR (charnum, ''.'') > 0
                        THEN
                           SUBSTR (charnum, INSTR (charnum, ''.'') + 1)
                        ELSE
                           NULL
                     END
                        AS decimal_part,
                     CASE
                        WHEN INSTR (charnum, ''.'') > 0
                        THEN
                           REPLACE (
                              REPLACE (
                                 SUBSTR (charnum,
                                         1,
                                         INSTR (charnum, ''.'') - 1),
                                 ''-'',
                                 ''''),
                              ''+'',
                              '''')
                        ELSE
                           REPLACE (REPLACE (charnum, ''-'', ''''), ''+'', '''')
                     END
                        AS integer_part,
                     CASE
                        WHEN INSTR (charnum, ''.'') > 0
                        THEN
                           LENGTH (
                              SUBSTR (charnum, INSTR (charnum, ''.'') + 1))
                        ELSE
                           0
                     END
                        AS length_of_decimal,
                     CASE
                        WHEN INSTR (charnum, ''.'') > 0
                        THEN
                           NVL (
                              LENGTH (
                                 REPLACE (
                                    REPLACE (
                                       SUBSTR (charnum,
                                               1,
                                               INSTR (charnum, ''.'') - 1),
                                       ''-'',
                                       ''''),
                                    ''+'',
                                    '''')),
                              0)
                        ELSE
                           NVL (
                              LENGTH (
                                 REPLACE (REPLACE (charnum, ''-'', ''''),
                                          ''+'',
                                          '''')),
                              0)
                     END
                        AS length_of_integer
                FROM (SELECT cast(col_name2 AS VARCHAR2 (50))
                                AS charnum
                        FROM YOUR_TABLE)) T1';

      q1 := REPLACE (q1, 'col_name2', rec.column_name);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE REPLACE (q1, 'col_name2', rec.column_name)
         INTO str
         USING rec.column_name;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (str);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Test cases:

```
create table precision_tester(test_val number);
```

--change YOUR_TABLE to PRECISION_TESTER

(run script, verify output, and delete from precision_tester after each test)

```
insert into precision_tester(test_val) values (null); 
insert into precision_tester(test_val) values (+1);
insert into precision_tester(test_val) values (-1);
insert into precision_tester(test_val) values (-1.00);
insert into precision_tester(test_val) values (+1.001);
insert into precision_tester(test_val) values (+12.001);
```

Yields the below dbms output:

```
cast( TEST_VAL as  NUMBER)
cast( TEST_VAL as  NUMBER(1,0))
cast( TEST_VAL as  NUMBER(1,0))
cast( TEST_VAL as  NUMBER(1,0))
cast( TEST_VAL as  NUMBER(4,3))
cast( TEST_VAL as  NUMBER(5,3))
```