# SQL to get all number that have more than 3 digits after the decimal point

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to get all number that have more than 3 digits after the decimal point.

For example, I have a table called `ARTICLE` that have two columns: `name` (`varchar` type) and `price` (`number`).

I would like to get all the record stored in table `ARTICLE` where the `price` column value have more than 3 numbers after the decimal point.

For example, `ARTICLE.price` value equal to 12.9584 or 45.874521 will be returned since they have more than 3 numbers after the decimal point.

How could I achieve this please?

I tried this request but it is not correct:

```
select name, price 
from ARTICLE 
where length(TO_CHAR(price)) > 7;
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using oracle?

Comment: Yes I use Oracle 11g

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the number of digits of an oracle number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941413/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-digits-of-an-oracle-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate on numbers only:

```
where trunc(price * 1000) - price * 1000 <> 0
```

Comment: The predicate may be simplified to `price < 0` which is probably not what was intended...possible `trunc` instead of `abs` was meant?

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing that out. Although a negative price might seem odd, it wasn't stated it cannot be below zero. In such case, it's safer to use `<>` comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ROUND` function - you are looking for number that *don't equal a rounded value to three digits*.

Example - you test data

```
select round(2/3,rownum) price from dual connect by level <= 5

     PRICE
----------
,7        
,67       
,667      
,6667     
,66667
```

Query to get numbers with more that 3 digits after the decimal point

```
with dt as (
select round(2/3,rownum) price from dual connect by level <= 5
)
select price from dt
where price != round(price,3)

     PRICE
----------
,6667     
,66667
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming to a similar solution than @Krzysztof:

```
CREATE TABLE article (name VARCHAR2(10), price NUMBER);

INSERT INTO article VALUES ('a', 12.9584);
INSERT INTO article VALUES ('b', 45.874521);
INSERT INTO article VALUES ('c', 0.123);


SELECT * FROM article WHERE ABS(price - TRUNC(price,3)) > 0;

NAME    PRICE
   a    12,9584
   b    45,874521
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a table to test this on, but you might be able to use:

```
Select Name, Price
From Article
Where Price like '%#.###%'
```

This would say that there has to be at least 1 number before the decimal, and at least 3 after the decimal. More info on the wildcard characters below:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You should definitively set up a test database and check your solution if it works before posting. This is the surest way how to gather up-votes;)  If you see it doesn't provide the expected result simple drop the answer. This will protect you against down-votes for a wrong answer.